# How to subtract subset of column from rest of column

Tags: r

I've got a data frame that includes 3 important variables for my work. The variables are CountryName, year, and Idealpoint. What I'm trying to do is find the difference in ideal points between the US and any individual country in a given year. So, for example, I want to calculate the difference in ideal points between the US and Croatia in 1993. How do I subset the US yearly idealpoint and subtract from it all the other countries data?

Here's what the data looks like

```
    year       Idealpoint    CountryName             

 1  1991       2.98 United States of America
 2  1992       3.00 United States of America
 3  1993       2.97 United States of America
 4  1994       3.00 United States of America
 5  1995       3.11 United States of America
 6  1996       3.12 United States of America
 7  1997       2.99 United States of America
 8  1998       2.72 United States of America
 9  1999       2.51 United States of America
10  2000       2.56 United States of America
```

There are other rows with different country names like Croatia, Sweden, etc...

I tried creating a subset vector of just US ideal point numbers and subtracting that from a subset of the above data without the US data. The problem is, not every country has an ideal point for every year, because in some cases the country didn't exist. So, the length of the US idealpoint vector is not a multiple of the length of the non-US vector. How do I get around that?

Ideally, what I'd like to see is something like (just an example, not what I expect to be actual results)

```
    year       Idealpoint    CountryName   DifIdealUS      

 1  1991       2.98            Latvia      1
 2  1992       3.00            Latvia      1.2    
 3  1993       2.97            Latvia      1.3
 4  1994       3.00            Latvia      1
 5  1995       3.11            Latvia      1.1
 6  1996       3.12            Latvia      1.2
 7  1997       2.99            Latvia      1.3
 8  1998       2.72            Latvia      1.6
 9  1999       2.51            Latvia      1.7
10  2000       2.56            Latvia      1.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(year) %>% 
   mutate(DifIdealUS = Idealpoint - 
                       Idealpoint[CountryName == 'United States of America'])
```

---

Or another option if the 'year' values are the same across all the 'CountryName' and is in `order`, then

```
df1$DifIdealUS <- df1$Idealpoint - 
        df1$Idealpoint[df1$CountryName == "United States of America"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more robust way to do this could be to extract the USA data into a new data frame and then left join it to `df1` by year. Then you can create a new column with the mutate function above without a group-by call - simply subtracting the USA data from the Idealpoint column.